# @ViewChild is undefined in Angular component, using angular2-signaturepad library

Tags: angular

I am developing an angular project with `angular2-signaturepad`. I'm trying to access a component in the template, so I created a @ViewChild. But when I try to use it, it's undefined.

Here's the relevant html snippet:

```html
<signature-pad [options]="options" (onBeginEvent)="drawBegin()" (onEndEvent)="drawComplete()"></signature-pad>
```

Here's the snippet from the typescript file:

```js
@ViewChild(SignaturePad, {static: true}) public signaturePad: SignaturePad;
```

Since `this.signaturepad` is undefined, I can't call any of its functions that I need. Can any one help me with this?

Comment: in the future, it could be helpful to indicate the place where you've accessed `this.signaturePad` and found it to be undefined (for example, in the constructor of the component, or ngOnInit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that could be happening here.

You could be trying to access the ViewChild before it exists. ViewChildren will be resolved before `ngAfterViewInit` is called ([more information on lifecycle events here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)), so you would only be able to guarantee that it's defined in that function. for example:

```
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnChanges {
    @ViewChild(SignaturePad, {static: true}) public signaturePad: SignaturePad;

    constructor() {
        console.log(this.signaturePad); // always undefined
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes) {
        console.log(this.signaturePad); // sometimes undefined, sometimes defined
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.signaturePad); // defined!
    }
```

The other thing that could be happening is the use of `static: true`, which means the ViewChild will be resolved before change detection ([more information on ViewChild here](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)). The implication of that would be, if `<signature-pad>` is nested inside of another element which happens to be conditional, then the ViewChild won't be resolved. for example:

```
<div *ngIf="allowEdit" class="my-container">
    <signature-pad ...></signature-pad>
</div>
```

Then in the class, the ViewChild would not be defined

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.signaturePad); // undefined
}
```

If this is your situation, then changing `{static: true}` to `{static: false}` should fix it

Comment: Yes it works ! I tried above ways and access component with local Refrence (#signaturepad).Thanks for your help ...Sir.

Comment: Hey @Panda, glad to hear it! It helps me out if you mark my answer as accepted, so I would appreciate that a bunch!